Equivalence of two strengthenings of open neighborhood
I'm currently pursuing a project (about Markov conditions in Minkowski spacetime) in which a certain equivalence between two strengthenings of open neighborhood plays an important role.
Say that set $N$ is an open line-wise neighborhood of set $X$ iff 1. $N$ is an open neighborhood of $X$, and 2. every continuous curve with one endpoint in $X$ and the other endpoint in the complement of $N\cup X$ has a non-trivial continuous subcurve in $N\backslash X$. (A curve is non-trivial iff it contains at least two points.)
Question: Let $V$ be any topological space homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm wondering if the following claim is true: for any subsets $S,T\subseteq V$, $S$ is an open neighborhood of $\bar{T}$ (the closure of $T$) iff $S$ is an open line-wise neighborhood of $T$?
So far I have an argument sketch for the left-to-right direction. It uses the following lemma:
Lemma: For any open set $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and continuous curve $c$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, if $c$ intersects $X$, then $c$ has a continuous non-trivial subcurve in $X$.
To see the left-to-right direction, suppose $S$ is an open neighborhood of $\bar{T}$. Let $c$ be a continuous curve with one endpoint in $(S\cup T)^c$ and the other endpoint in $T$. W.l.o.g. we can assume that $c$ has its starting point in $(S\cup T)^c$. Since $c$ is continuous, it intersects $T$'s boundary, $\partial T$, and since $\bar{T}$ is closed, there is a first point $q$ in $\bar{T}$ which $c$ intersects. Since $S$ is an open neighborhood of $\bar{T}$, there is an open ball $B_q$ with $q\in B_q\subseteq S$. Suppose, for contradiction, that $c$ doesn't intersect $B_q\cap \bar{T}^c$. Then, since $B_q$ is open, by the Lemma, $c$ has a non-trivial continuous subcurve in $B_q\cap \bar{T}$. But then $q$ isn't the first point at which $c$ intersects $\bar{T}$. So $c$ intersects $B_q\cap \bar{T}^c$. Hence it intersects $S\cap \bar{T}^c$. But $S\cap \bar{T}^c$ is open, and so, again by the Lemma, $c$ has a non-trivial continuous subcurve in $S\cap \bar{T}^c$. Hence it has a non-trivial continuous subcurve in $S\cap T^c$. Since $c$ was arbitrary, $S$ is an open line-wise neighborhood of X. $\blacksquare$
I'm less sure about the right-to-left direction.
EDIT: Changed some names, and simplified exposition, in response to comments.

Your definition of open neighbourhood is not the standard one, see e.g. wikipedia. For example, with your definition, if $X$ is open and not closed, then $X$ is not an open neighbourhood of itself. Are you sure you want this notion of open neighbourhood?

Thanks! I am interested indeed in the definition as I originally wrote it; I edited the question (and simplified it) to reflect that my original definition wasn't the standard definition. In the edited question "open neighborhood" now denotes the standard notion (an open set containing the given set).

The other implication seems to be false. For instance, take $X = \lbrace \frac{1}{n} : n = 2,3,4,\ldots\rbrace$ and $N = ]0,1[$ subsets of $\mathbb R$. Then $N$ is open, but does not contain $0\in \bar X$, hence it is not open neighborhood of $\bar X$.
To see that it is open line-wise neighborhood of $X$, assume first that you have a continuous curve that has an endpoint at $t \leq 0$, which does not belong to $N$, and another endpoint at $1/n$. Then there is a subcurve contained in $]\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}[$, which is contained in $N - X$.
If the curve begins at $t \geq 1$, then there is a subcurve contained in $]\frac{1}{2},1[$.
A counter-example for any $\mathbb R^n$ would be: let $N$ be the open ball of radius 1 punctured at the origin, and let $X$ be the union of all spheres of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geq 2$. Then $0\in\bar X$ hence $N$ does not contain $\bar X$. If a curve begins at the origin and finishes at the sphere of radius $\frac{1}{n}$, then there is a subcurve between the spheres of radius $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$. If it begins outside of $N$ and the origin, there is a subcurve between the sphere of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ and the border of $N$.
The implication you sketched is correct: to make it more formal, if $c\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R^n$ the first point $q$ exists because the preimage of $\bar T$ is compact in $[0,1]$ therefore there is a minimum (not infimum) $t_1$ such that for all $t < t_1$, $c(t) \in \mathbb R^n - \bar T$ and $c(t_1)\in\bar T$.
Then, pick an open ball around $q$, $B_q \subseteq S$ which you can take since $\bar T \subseteq S$ and $S$ is open, then $c^{-1}(B_q)$ is an open neighbourhood of $t_1$, hence you can pick $t_0 < t_1$ such that for all $t \in ]t_0,t_1[$ you have $c(t) \in S$, from where you can pick a non-trivial subcurve contained in $S$.

Thank you very much, this is great!

A follow-up question: I'm thinking of slightly strengthening the definition of open line-wise neighborhood. Say that  is a strong open line-wise neighborhood of set  iff 1.  is an open neighborhood of , and 2. every continuous curve which starts in the complement of ∪ and ends in   has a non-trivial continuous subcurve in ∖ *before ever intersecting  *. Might there be a way to prove that all strong open line-wise neighborhoods of R are open neighborhoods of R's closure?

@Jens when you write R, you mean $\mathbb R$ or is it just a subset of $\mathbb R^n$?

I mean just a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ -- sorry, should have made clearer.

In your counterexample, since zero is not in $S$, you can pick the line going from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ and it meets $T$ but not $S-T$.

Yeah, I realized too --- I've already deleted the comment...

Hmmm it might be true, i think it goes like this: assume $N$ is SOLW nbhd of $X$ but $\bar X $ is not contained in $N$, then since $X\subseteq N$ there exists $x_0\in (\bar X - N)$. This is actually a limit point, so for each $1/n$ you can pick an element in $x_n \in X\cap B_{1/n}(x_0)$. Define $c\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R^n$ so that $c(0) = x_0$, $c(1/n) = x_n$ and in $]1/(n+1),1/n[$ it is the straight line between $x_{n+1},x_n$. I think this is a continuous curve contradicting the hypothesis that $N$ is SOLW nbhd. Am i right that it is continuous at $0$?

Nice! I should be continuous at 0 right? Sketchily: Let $c^:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be any ("back"-)extension of $c$ such that $c^\vert_{[-1,0]}$ is continuous. (Should be possible to always choose such a $c^$.) But now it should follow from your construction that for every open ball $B_r(0)$ around $0$, $(c^)^{-1}(B_r(0))$ is an open interval around $0$. The same should go for balls around the rest of the points. Since in $\mathbb{R}^n$ every open set is a (countable) union of open balls, and countable unions of open intervals are open, continuity would follow.
